# Someone plagiarized my question when cross-posting, and now it's locked. How do I unlock it?

Tags: support, specific-question, locked

I recently asked a question on Stack Overflow about some code I had written, but was told to post it on here instead. I did this, whilst making some amendments to make it more suitable for Code Review. However, somebody else exactly copied my question from Stack Overflow and pasted it here, before I posted my amended question.

So now the question that I asked is locked, and I don't really know what to do about it. I'd quite like for somebody to review the code, but that isn't going to happen if nothing changes.

My question can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159943/raycasting-algorithm-in-pygame).

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you did all the right things, by reposting the question here with modifications, deleting the original Stack Overflow question, and flagging the issue for moderator attention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moderators lock questions when they need to cool things down. There's nothing an ordinary user can do about it.

This time we just needed some time to figure out what was going on. Since neither 200_success or myself (who were the present moderators at the time) has 10k reputation on Stack Overflow, we were not 100% sure about who was the original poster of the question.

Things are now sorted out, the code that someone else posted has been marked as duplicate and your question has been unlocked.

Time is 7:35 pm (UTC) and all is well.

Comment: I'm approaching 20K on SO - next time ping me =)